# Laravel middleware routing inside views folder Error 404| Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, view

In my laravel application i have successfully implemented middleware and works fine but inside views folder i have a folder for marketing team named market and inside of it i have marketing.blade.php file so when user by marketing role logged in it routes it to marketing.blade.php. but error **Not found |404** is displaying. here is my implementation

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->userRole == '1') // marketing
        {
            
         return redirect('market.marketing');

        }
}
```

To solve this i have tried the following commands

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dumpautoload
```

i couldnt solve it.

Comment: you redirect to URLs (routes) not views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return redirect('market.marketing');
```

**here you used vie directory. but here will be url. look like this**

`return redirect('market/marketing');` **Note: it is (market/marketing) not your directory name. it will be your url path.**

**Or you can use name route.

```
 return redirect()->route('market.marketing');
```

web.php file**

```
Route::get('/market/marketing', 'YourControllerName@MethodName')->name('market.marketing');
```

**I think it will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

`redirect()` is for routes.
use `view()` instead of it.

```
return view('market.marketing');
```

Comment: thanks but error Call to a member function setCookie() on null
 happend

Comment: create a route for this view and redirect to that route